How do I catch a specific exception in JavaScript?
In Python, you can catch a specific exception like this:
try:
    [1, 2, 3][4]
except IndexError:
    print("index is out of range")

How do I achieve the same thing in JavaScript? I tried this:
class NegativeIntegerError extends Error {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message)
        this.message = message
    }
}
class NegativeRangeNotSupportedError extends Error {
    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message)
        this.message = message
    }
}
export function range(start: number, stop: number, step: number = 1): number[] {
    if (start < 0 || stop < 0 || step < 0) {
        throw new NegativeRangeNotSupportedError("Negative range start, stop, or step is not supported for now. Please use a positive range.")
    }
    let res: number[] = []
    for (let index: number = start; index <= stop; index += step) {
        res.push(index)
    }
    return res
}
export function getDivisors(number: number): number[] {
    try {
        return range(1, number).filter((element) => (number % element == 0))
    } catch (message: any | unknown) {
         if (message.includes("error TS119: Expression Expected."))
            throw new NegativeIntegerError("Could not get divisors of a negative number.")
         else
            console.log("there is nothing to cause an error what")
    }
}

but I get the error message "message.includes" is not a function. Is there an another way to handle a specific exception?

message is the error object, message.message.includes(...) would work.

i tried that but did not get what i expected
...
    if (message.message.includes("error TS119: Expression Expected."))
                throw new NegativeIntegerError("Could not get divisors of a negative number.")
            else
                console.log("there is nothing to cause an error what")
...

and the result:

it returns
there is nothing to cause an error what
undefined
~``

oh shoot those markdown does not work on comments

There are several ways, basically, but you can't treat an error object like it's a string. Check a property: https://github.com/CodeYourFuture/tech-products-demo/blob/9078480090ba185d847f90adcf9d60b27c27aad4/server/resources/resourcesRepository.js#L35-L40. Check the type: https://github.com/CodeYourFuture/tech-products-demo/blob/9078480090ba185d847f90adcf9d60b27c27aad4/server/resources/resourcesController.js#L52-L59. You can't catch only specific errors, JavaScript doesn't support that, but you can re-throw when it's not the error you wanted to catch.

ohh ok, lemme read it

oh wait i think the instanceof is the solution

You can check the instanceof error.
Something like:
try {
    // Code that might throw an exception
    throw new Error("Something went wrong");
} catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
        // Handle specific error types
        console.log("Error occurred:", error.message);
    } else {
        // Catch all other types of errors
        console.log("Unknown error occurred");
    }
}

